# How to start the WPF window from console programmatically?

Tags: wpf

I have a `WPF` window, I want to know if I can start it from a console programmatically?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Hi You can use Application Class, with the help of this class,we can start wpf window programmatically,

```
Application app = new Application ();
app.Run(new Window1());
```

Comment: Note: be sure to add `[STAThread]` attribute to the `Main` method.

Comment: won't work without the comment above. you will still get the "STA" error message.

Answer (score 7):

Use the [`Application` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms588794.aspx):

```
new Application().Run(new SomeWindow());
```