# Re-Open WPF Window from a Console application

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms, console-application

I want to open a WPF Window from a Console application. After referring to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4509714/how-to-start-the-wpf-window-from-console-programmatically), it works fine.

The problem is: When the user closed the WPF Window (manually), it can  no long be re-opened from the Console, throwing the exception message: "Cannot create more than one System.Windows.Application instance in the same AppDomain."

Here is the code:

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string input=null;
            while ((input = Console.ReadLine()) == "y")
            {
                //Works fine at the first iteration,
                //But failed at the second iteration.
                StartWpfThread();
            }
        }
        private static void OpenWindow()
        {
            //Exception(Cannot create more than one System.Windows.Application instance in the same AppDomain.)
            //is thrown at the second iteration.
            var app = new System.Windows.Application();
            var window = new System.Windows.Window();
            app.Run(window);
            //User  closes the opened window manually.
        }
        private static void StartWpfThread()
        {
            var thread = new Thread(() =>
            {
                OpenWindow();
            });
            thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            thread.IsBackground = false;
            thread.Start();
        }
    }
```

How can I re-open the WPF Window?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You should not create the application together with the window but only once separately, also make sure that it does not exit  after the window is closed by setting the `ShutdownMode` respectively, e.g.

```
class Program
{
    static Application app;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var appthread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() =>
            {
                app = new Application();
                app.ShutdownMode = ShutdownMode.OnExplicitShutdown;
                app.Run();
            }));
        appthread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        appthread.Start();

        while (true)
        {
            var key =Console.ReadKey().Key;
            // Press 1 to create a window
            if (key == ConsoleKey.D1)
            {
                // Use of dispatcher necessary as this is a cross-thread operation
                DispatchToApp(() => new Window().Show());
            }
            // Press 2 to exit
            if (key == ConsoleKey.D2)
            {
                DispatchToApp(() => app.Shutdown());
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    static void DispatchToApp(Action action)
    {
        app.Dispatcher.Invoke(action);
    }
}
```

Also if you want to re-open the very same window make sure it is never closed completely, to do that you can handle the `Closing` event and cancel it using `e.Cancel = true;`, then just call `Hide` on the window to "close" it and `Show` to "open" it again later.

Comment: Are there any negative consequences to not running the app in another thread, and never calling app.Run()? I.e just create a new Application object, then a new Window object and just call myWindow.ShowDialog(). From what I can tell, a dispatcher is created and attached to the current thread automatically, and Application.Current is still used to manage resources.

Comment: @Matt: That is not something you usually do, so i don't know as i never did that. You can also have windows without any Application it seems...

Answer (score 0):

When you add window as a parameter to app.Run you link the lifetime of your app to your window. Don't do that:

```
private static void OpenWindow()
        {
            //Exception(Cannot create more than one System.Windows.Application instance in the same AppDomain.)
            //is thrown at the second iteration.
            var app = new System.Windows.Application();
            var window = new System.Windows.Window();
            app.Run();
            window.Show();
            //User  closes the opened window manually.
        }
```

Comment: Thanks!But atfter i separating the Window.Show() from the app.Run() method, the window never get shown.

Comment: In addition to a form you can also pass an ApplicationContext to run. I don't know how it works but maybe in that class lies a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've not had chance to test this myself, but after reading up on your error, I found some information. Basically, it sounds like the `AppDomain` you are running in can only be used once per application - so perhaps you need to create a new `AppDomain` each time you want to re-create the application. See [here](http://www.infosysblogs.com/microsoft/2008/10/working_with_application_domai_1.html) for some more information on this.

Alternately, you could use `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(...)` in order to fire off the application properly. Refer [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx) for the documentation for the `Process` class.

Finally, if you are just wanting to allow the user to run the application from the command line, it might be simpler to write a command script and execute that from the command line.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, in my application the WPF Window will share many variables from the Console Application, so they have to be running in the same process.