# How to open WPF window from Console Application

Tags: c#, wpf

I have just made a simple Console Application and i would like to open WPF window now. I added WPF item to my Application :P. But i have no idea how to Open this window from my Main(). I hope some1 can help me :).

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8047610/re-open-wpf-window-from-a-console-application) [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4509714/how-to-start-the-wpf-window-from-console-programmatically) [Here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/dbc8b14c-d523-4237-997a-c55588f04c2c/calling-a-wpf-control-from-a-console-application?forum=wpf)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
Application app = new Application();
app.Run(new Window1());
```

Comment: I hope that Window1() is a WPF's name?

It simply doesnt work for me i have tried almost every single combination.

    `var app = new Application();
    app.Run(new UserControl1()); //UserControl1 is my WPF's window name`

And here's my WPF's code:

   `public partial class UserControl1
    {
        public UserControl1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Test");
        }
    }`

Comment: @user2871989 You need to use a `Window` not a `UserControl`.

Comment: I was trying to resolve this problem. But i am still stuck. I managed to make this--->   `[STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var app = new Application();
            app.Run(new Window());
        }` a new window will appear. But my WPF's Window is already there and i just want to Initialize it from Main() ;/. i am confused

Comment: @user2871989  Dont use `new Window()`. you have to create a new Window, like you have created a new UserControl.  It should be like `public partial class MyWindow : Window`.  The contents of your `UserControl` should be on that window, rather than the usercontrol (or you could place the usercontrol on the window).